# Is there a way to set the ripple color for a Floating Action Button through XML Attributes?

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I see that there is a setRippleColor method but I was wondering if I could avoid changing the color of the Floating Action Button programatically. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `app:rippleColor`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this `app:rippleColor="@color/your_ripple_color"`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set clickable too.

```
app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:clickable="true"
```